# How can I make this Max MSP/M4L patch update zl.len and zl.mth for an empty list?

Tags: max-msp-jitter, ableton-live

#### Background

I'm trying to build a Max for Live device as a solution to the problem presented in [this related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/107033/72712). As part of my solution I need to keep track of a group of notes (i.e. the selected, or in-scale notes).

My patch (see below) works great for any combination of held notes, but fails once the last note is released. When that happens, `zl.len` stays stuck at 1 and `zl.mth` continues to output whatever note was released last.

#### The question

How can I update my patch so that the length is 0 and the selected note is empty when the input list of held notes is empty?

#### What I have tried

I have tried banging the left inlet of the various `zl` objects manually and as part of the `kslider` update but this only produces the same unwanted behavior.

Here is a screen-shot of the patch:

[image: Screen-shot of Max patcher]

and here is the corresponding code:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
917.3ocyX0zbaCBD8ryL4+.iN6jAPHaodr8P+AzicxjQePrIUB4AgRcal9eu
7gUrSprJJF5zKlQqA18s6agmzyWe0hnh18ztHvG.eErXwyJKKL1zVVLXXQTS
99x57NyDi38METQzxC+m5QFulJM+I5Dqs8xAy3AypoxZ5az1fKOt4C1Pur9c
4h7FpjJtmxyKpouZE1cV9icTajGEsDDUjy2DAtaXNrJSv1V73MIwQG2VY4VF
ey8BZoztXbRxsvk.BYkdHNV+KFeKDbmYM+55qzipgkNmgJaaZnb4KdUR2abV
zmZ64RfbKErkVWA3sRUxeXV0LNsTOgWkwbI8BGCz3o.8ZnArYFLmhLOPtHLW
zKks7YwJdmE6IJzvovLxVniIolRLY32PTn+nJFM0YcIFnfPzkVOIYSgsXnkD
mYpqnDy.FFFv8EpDv3Uz8f1G.UzNlfVA5Jyqo2ng6kC0zI6WyHmzuhxPAEps
BosMUgXPdWIkWoBGPqnZlGANJPWOMPOzWlY.55rPBzOKZ628lSlTPV1BxA0r
NOveSlj+d3zWHxVTiCM+cn2zTW0OX3uWNJm7pFBw1dptdIwWco+Obta7j20f
WYNvkj5uyc4zuq76eVY+Y8scpN1wyF3+h1jQUULNfwS23FSN4hFBxCJJNGfk
B1lMTAn38Q.lQMFSlDxqSsMtlCoRhCHj2ITGKA5n0JmSqt3NVLxgRYhkBmBC
HtTb2F41fScQYtfW6PPot153F88NWbQDs1AwQGT6tZUXKhSfHeVFW4P6XLzP
XSBeYrlx2bNx6bpiwNHfmfMfy1RFt5nBRguJ5zKrX4swq8.d+VWM6TkqsO7P
G03tUv2EXmmDBlVNlc3X9nosh9JdhPcIj0BdjbV5z5HMoLDz9hsjgaiB.EoH
eyr3GnIyJiSOb.pXqlRblVR4nrC6Va97Bu8K8X1V8e7lDPWaunbH7F9DJ.3w
fT8VeRFOWxTROONK8cK.zT4ZmcnVgkiN7jYYesLcx1CgfVUq6gfGb3aQy3NT
KXwSNzwjL7LIYrGBgD3bBAefYhSI40ADyNl1OWH.+mkEzhLBV6kigP.SBoNw
DHALGfbi8G6uiXVMG1uOb3b3YdplhbgTg7l67FG9vE04618DUzcXOr9VII4w
VyhRWZelwsOakUDInOwFVRh0TtPIYPpzKzKLgbz9UGdGdijKAumMvi0nW6Zi
pGtRPW2tbKNMpit9J0D9MXvABqM
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the only way to know if there is nothing in a `zl group` object is to somehow keep track of whether something came in.

Here is an example that should do what you are looking for if I understand correctly:

[image]

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1066.3ocwY1rbaaCDG+rzSAFdVQC9fe1iIGxCPO1wiGJQXYlRBpgDLUsYx6d
AVPZoXCICYBxbQ1DBlK9s6+cwB3erdUvtlS7t.zef9KzpU+X8pUvP5AVM77p
f57S6qx6foEH3+SytuErw7UR9IILrDsCUNNZYALlZdehMNlnutTTwkvagbdv
ld43nzgQMCI+2ibyBKXWt3PvFTPoPYrGFl0wb49mKEGdrkuWZlHkw1Ri1fHL
5V7FDMaq5Ap52QOn+a94505O1LMRsQI0JkTqTRtFkuGcDEcJpBYwyGbRD1VP
L5NhhSkOFk.7QG+zm70wqPXDwFigVYjYkQ16oTG+oK.SS.fCCmCfslSxVP4J
MjNmx0R6AShOJ6nI7dp5jk5CR6q2waGW9puprtuFV7j2xYzKQxi4s40bIu8Q
tHeWEf.1C9fWDy2zCDEBdfHLFxfYmUxibTJF4.+AbJ6apq45nwqh+eooWHQx
m4nm4UEHQiTsY1vjpJE785u+R9tz2QuCMB95vaJGGFBPmRFc.enf+tdorQXQ
PGg8TflbyJW2LeFm.fhGRqG+7CA50BneVsJf3oNThTKRK9hvLOE3vCpVSkWR
DHdoXOizexUUoDE7SnlmPE7txVdApaedE+SZHsAXpe.jlwtLsjjQlG.aZklT
OEmn7t8bQgZgfZZKNWH6R7R7EdX.OVHT2kjjMK3801l9iupFiBTYCJGUU1YU
gF4YBoCAP1roPGy4fXn9APgZiMlux9.XhX5cKmZt2Uqaxn+1qaRiSFJyP8Pg
yqzHz+UssSkFZ6nII2Qyd2rM.mZBZHYLjLGMyBGxz5ITng2gpj4x4LcowOro
vCFfMNaNP9XqZUfTGaQYUdgMxIdpVyP.L1bvqT7bPiRlVKe1BEjrEUkFkNip
TSH6fdaCajl32tWXlMEhimo30U4HdYqqX1BLZFiXUbwA6hSOsk23E3XNueb5
LEwTbXCB7hDuHQT8F5CmRfkLIF+6tpxK5gr4om53fchwuEvz6dmd57bc.lcE
LnmFNzjyEGEtofeo7oUsoiY.p+jA6xOXSCrD26yKWGhQfGktMw18g.uB3P5u
55mgWod7ek5tl918iqgg3M5rWUcvJYoHWVpZC77bzsEftl1yUCM9Rtokz2ol
erD0EKQ7gkHumk7.RLG7cDOYGxBXG8Ew79xNenEbww4kHTzBQDYwbcIt3690
Ui4xJzUCmjoScTFN072Hmxqx7fkXNU8KxGBQWpIoa6b5VxEuGyG6cvntFmlr
kHtTQ2G6cvHtvT7hkHmYOQlr.lNwtowSqNYlK0I8wlYiAoaaoDeXIWR3dKRl
lDyOd7671tgYC1P0D72Z.ec5l0l++RlGg1VCZ4eubb9lIj2p5SUpZRsuEVWA
mhMWYDzOdqnubPynnSYRnAag5XDcGyMf.8gu9mq+eNu4kL.
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your code keeps track? I see that it works for length, but I'm a noob at Max programming and am not sure how to extend it to fix the selected note output as well.

Comment: Currently it only keeps track of whether or not a note is selected. In this patch, indeed if you want to clear the [zl mth] when no notes are selected you can do a [sel 0] after [i ] and use that to send `zlclear` to your [zl mth], as you did in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the Cycling74 forum, I came up with this solution that uses `borax` to count the held notes, and as a trigger to clear the `zl` object when the count is 0.

[image: screen-shot of selected-note patch]

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
866.3ocuX1zaaBCFG+bxmBKzNlEgMP.lTOsO.6vNNMUYHtItCLHioKqU869r
eLrzlBIPBrKfvA3u+87N4kkKbRJNvpbPeA8CzhEurbwBXIyBKZtdgSN8PZFs
BtMmzh7blP4rx9aJ1AEr92j6nB9yLjZOCIJTrJDWnJPTTUgTw1hx3U+6ox3B
VZQs.dTulEE04E0pLlBDxsY0RpJcOWr6dIKUY2nDb7Z2UHOhm4TD1bzObsK5
mMOCeKrkJRd7ydwNGe8bQ6aGaV60kKMGVcij+0LFUBXq29k0JD+AsAnwFPkL
zdV11NI2erj6ERLvRb8MmBgiab6g7vYm7uyxzas24wgKpRoYrNIlLZhcAmre
75fUHbfK3385g3fIiXA62523G.VgdNK03tc5jC7YhYii.O2Ff.KGDxa3v9ZT
+ojYe.mVk5hTRzbSpNF9SbL5t6PtFWp.gGg+b.1AaD7F3BufyYG5z.fcmaCP
Rgjdna2b7YvyEHB6A3gsAum2OyMIVW4oNiM5zx3cMVl57DVOg5jyjxFrA7pg
gsIqmXBzhvyqyAGFtW2tFwDpXWmLF347O8kzblhIumInIYr2VNQieqNtSUzR
RsRUHFc5umIFWaL7gSD+1i8GVzK6djgv9bkV7b1ZS+7QGTfC7so5PCLe7kyK
LA.cGf2ciMxTVlOYzd3F.aJrQHWFvd8vD+4t3VoTW8.UAsuYacF8.X1h39a.
2XzGal8VXvNyeHYtZ+niHagfDdyQj334NhTy3NYQc4Um2YmUN3lnbyjQ4upx
3auhVK3X6j+vzfQ.YAdCr45w1OEaYuMYVpyCsKP9HzQCoXawCOTwT8V9cBiC
Rn6F+nmVyUynmD6EWbjjNi.tX..7TvHhm7Qkv9xr96YtpnVl1JaapD53VaKq
RwETEW2y83MYpoXtoNsqCVoMCQovoPoAHT6t4lDJZHDMQ5fGfN3aTGy6v6RF
tIfGiN9CPmofGxkzw8cNwBooNooxxsor+HhAOUZ7rC8IauoR4AA8rXtCGhxw
SQsE2gjyGMEIIQ+uXx70cCSoaMgzibcLYayQKKehIqZtaPDcS7GKf.nnUKse
Bp8Rn+rij8Du89g+1SGpT2tVo6UWKgMlygM1o+gwTjhZdSdfFOsjv.BB8fHU
kTKIvbDKec4eADs2DjA
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: Looking good! [borax] is maybe a bit overkill for this, but hey, it does the job.You could in this case replace the if statement with a [sel 0] if you'd like to simplify further.